# Selective Import from CSV to MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import

How would I import certain rows from a large csv file into a MySQL table.
I know how to import all the data but my problem is that my csv file is too large and I don't need all the data that it has.

I only want to import rows where the "COLUMN_X" has either of these values [VALID1, VALID2, VALID3]
All other rows with invalid values for column_x should be ignored.

Can anyone help me do that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can't filter out rows with the LOAD DATA INFILE, so either filter these out by pre-processing the CSV file or load the data into a temporary table and insert the relevant rows into your main table, something like;

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE import LIKE my_main_table;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv' into import;
INSERT INTO my_main_table SELECT * FROM import
                          WHERE column_x IN(VALID1, VALID2, VALID3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO mytable
 (column1, @dummy, @dummy, column2, column3)
```

which would load only the 1st, 4th, and 5th columns into the database. But you'd need to know which position your "good" columns are ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [comments to mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( .....) 
PARTITION BY LIST (COLUMN_X)
(
   PARTITION main VALUE IN (VALID1, VALID2, VALID3)
);
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_file.csv' IGNORE INTO your_table .....
```

If you need to append data to an existing table, you can create a new temporary table and import data into it as described above, and then `INSERT INTO old_table SELECT * FROM your_table`;

Answer (score 1):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' IGNORE
INTO TABLE `table` (field1, field2, @pk, field3, @columnx)
SET pk = IF (@columnx IN ('VALID1', 'VALID2', 'VALID3'), NULL, 'key'),
    COLUMN_X = @columnx
```

- `IGNORE` ignores rows if a duplicate key is found in the CSV.
- `(field1, field2, @pk, field3, @columnx)` is the mapping of CSV columns to values. Specifically: the first field of the CVS goes into column `field1`, the second field of the CVS goes into column `field2`, the thirs field of the CSV goes into variable `@pk`, etc.
- `pk =` Sets the column named `pk` to whatever the result of the expression following the `=` is. In this case, it sets the column `pk` to `NULL` if one of the valid values are encountered in the fifth column of the CSV. Otherwise it sets that column to `'key'`

This works if `pk` is the column that holds the primary key, the table already has a record with `'key'` as primary key and the column with the primary key is set to `auto_increment`.