# how to enter data into mysql table with wrong date format

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a CSV file with lots of different columns, with one column having date which is in DD-MM-YYYY format . now mysql's default format is YYYY-MM-DD . I was planning to load my CSV file directly into my mysql table , but this may cause a problem. what should I do . PS- i am not planning to run a code from some other language on the file , so i would appreciate solutions that include the use of mysql itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to perform multiple steps you could first import the csv into an intermediate table which has the same properties as your real data table, except for the date columns.

Then you can just insert it into the real table and format the date-string while selecting

```
INSERT INTO realTable (/* ... */) 
    SELECT /*.... */, STR_TO_DATE('01-5-2013','%d-%m-%Y') 
    FROM intermediateTable;
```

When ready truncate the table, done. Should be done in a transaction so you can rollback if something goes wrong.

edit: 
Seems to be a better way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4963561/3595565 So you should be able to format the date while importing by using a variable

Comment: ah this may work , so you saying intermediate table has the date column as string ?

Comment: Yes. But while looking into this topic I found another way, might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things.

1. Since your column format is DD-MM-YYYY directly you can't convert YYYY-MM-DD.You can use substr to get DD, MM, YYYY seperately and insert in your table.
2. Otherwise you can store as varchar not date type.